# Check if one of the values from both lists are present in the string in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two arrays with logins and file extensions:
logins = ['bob', 'mark', 'joe']
extensions = ['.doc', '.xls']

I need to check if one of the values from both lists are present in the string (string is like str = "aaa bob test.txt test text"), and if yes do some work.

How to correctly perform this checking in Ruby.

Now I'm perform this with several loop and if statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[logins, extensions].all? do |list|
  list.any? { |match| str.include? match }
end
```

You have two lists, logins and extensions. You want to make sure that `all?` of them do something and that 'something' is that the string includes `any?` of their elements.

The answer using regex is better performing, though, even if a little less simple to write.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`Regexp.union`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Regexp.html#method-c-union) :

```
str = 'aaa bob test.xls test text'
logins     = Regexp.union(['bob', 'mark', 'joe'])
extensions = Regexp.union(['.doc', '.xls'])
str =~ logins && str =~ extensions
# => 12
```

It returns either `nil` if one of both didn't match or an integer if both matched.

As an alternative, with Ruby 2.4 :

```
str.match?(logins) && str.match?(extensions)
```

which would return a boolean.

Comment: Thanks, this is more readable for me but works less slower. The result application has login array with about 500 records.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the array to get the union with unique vales and then iterate to check if the string has a matching value.

```
   str = 'aaa bob test.txt test text'
  (logins + extensions).any? { |word| str.include?(word) }
```

This returns 'true' or 'false'